# add multiple dropdowns using a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form where I need to get the values of 10 optional dropdowns, each dropdown has a name that goes from 0 to 9 to differentiate them on submit (dropdown1,dropdown2...), why optional? because the user can add them with a button, for example a user can click a button to to add a dropdown options and it will get the name as dropdown and adds the count number to the name untill I have 10 as maximum. I have been trying to accomplish this without any luck any one can point me or show me how I can do this

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: name them as `dropdown[]`

Comment: Here is what I have, I need to create a new dropdown everytime I click Add more then add/change the number on each name, untill I have 10
http://jsfiddle.net/2syqtw7e

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable and update it's value on creation of new dropdown. Once the variable value has reached 10 stop creating dropdown

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var _dropDownCount =1; //Create a variable
   /* btn click event */
    $('#addmore').click(function(){
        /* append selectbox where you want */
        //Check if variable value is less than 10 then
        // and only then create more dropdown
        if(_dropDownCount <=10){ 
        $("#target").append('<select name="dropdown1"><option value="">select</option></select>');
        _dropDownCount++; // Update variable value on creation of dropdown
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2syqtw7e/1/)